# How to create a branch under another branch in git?

Tags: git, branch

I'm just curious, because I've noticed that some repositories have their branches setup like this:

```
git branch -a

master
remotes/origin/branch1
remotes/origin/branch2/lala
remotes/origin/branch2/yay
remotes/origin/branch3
remotes/origin/branch4
```

I'm just curious how they do the branch `lala` and `yay` under branch2; or is that not a branch?

Any insight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `branch2/lala` and `branch2/yay` branches aren't really “under” a branch named `branch2`.  Each is just a normal branch, whose names happens to contain a `/`.

```
:; cd /tmp
:; mkdir gittest
:; cd gittest
:; mkdir origin
:; cd origin
:; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/gittest/origin/.git/
:; touch somefile
:; git add somefile
:; git commit -m 'initial commit'
[master (root-commit) 4d62ed7] initial commit
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 somefile
:; git branch branch1
:; git branch branch2/lala
:; git branch branch2/yay
:; git branch branch3
:; git branch branch4
:; git branch -a
  branch1
  branch2/lala
  branch2/yay
  branch3
  branch4
* master

:; cd ..
:; git clone origin local
Cloning into 'local'...
done.
:; cd local
:; git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/branch1
  remotes/origin/branch2/lala
  remotes/origin/branch2/yay
  remotes/origin/branch3
  remotes/origin/branch4
  remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense - thanks. I think the reason I was confused, was because I was getting the error: `error: unable to create directory for .git/refs/heads/branch1/lala
fatal: Failed to lock ref for update: No such file or directory`. I figured out that I'm getting this error because the `branch1` already exists, and it doesn't like me creating another one with `/lala` appended onto that.